# Better Design for eliminate duplicates after union query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, union

I'm designing a UNION query to merge two tables with customer informations in a oracle 11g database. The first table **a** is the 'major' source the second table **b** is a additional source with **new and duplicate** entries.

The duplicates in **b** can not be eliminated by using UNION in fact of not equal fields like the autoincremented ID which is necessary to select.

Table **a**

`ID CUSTOMER_NUMBER NAME       STREET
 1  4711            Dirk       Downstreet 4 
 2  4721            Hans       Mainstreet 5`

Table **b**

`ID CUSTOMER_NUMBER NAME       STREET
 44 4711            Dirk       Downstreet 4 <== Duplicate
 4  4741            Harry      Crossroad 9  <== new`

**Expected Result**

`ID CUSTOMER_NUMBER NAME       STREET       DATASOURCE
 1  4711            Dirk       Downstreet 4 SAP        <== from a
 2  4721            Hans       Mainstreet 5 SAP        <== from a
 4  4741            Harry      Crossroad 9  MANUAL     <== from b`

I'm pretty happy with the following - simplified - trial:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUMBER, 
    MAX(ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATASOURCE DESC) ID,
    MAX(NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATASOURCE DESC) NAME,
    MAX(STREET) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATASOURCE DESC) STREET,
FROM 
    (SELECT "ID","CUSTOMER_NUMBER","NAME","STREET", 'SAP' as DATASOURCE FROM CUSTOMERS
        UNION ALL
    SELECT "ID","CUSTOMER_NUMBER","NAME","STREET", 'MANUAL' as DATASOURCE FROM CUSTOMERS_MANUAL) united
group by CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

But I have to SELECT every single field by DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DATASOURCE DESC which are about 20 fields ...

Can anyone show me a better approch?

Comment: Some sample data with expected output will really help.

Comment: Are there likely to be multiple rows for the same customer number, name and street in each datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to `KEEP` for each column is to use `ROW_NUMBER` with the partitioning on your unique key and propper order and select only the row with the number one.

Example for `CUSTOMER_NUMBER`as unique key, prefering `MANUAL`over `SAP` and expecting the `ID` is unique in each source.:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
   "ID","CUSTOMER_NUMBER","NAME","STREET",
   roww_number() over (partition by CUSTOMER_NUMBER order by decode(DATASOURCE,'SAP',2,'MANUAL',1), ID) as RN
FROM 
    (SELECT   "ID","CUSTOMER_NUMBER","NAME","STREET", 'SAP' as DATASOURCE FROM CUSTOMERS
        UNION ALL
     SELECT   "ID","CUSTOMER_NUMBER","NAME","STREET", 'MANUAL' as DATASOURCE FROM CUSTOMERS_MANUAL) united
) WHERE RN = 1
```

This works fine even in case that the individual sources deliver duplicates. Adjust the order columns so, that the query remains deterministic, i.e. repeated query provides the same result (e.g. add `NAME` if the `ID` column can be duplicated in `SAP`)

Comment: This is pretty smart and exactly what I was looking for. Never worked with partition by so far. Need further readings about that. But works fine for me. Thank you!